# Last Account Activity in Gmail

Tags: google-account

In Gmail, at the bottom of the page it says *Last account activity*. Is there a way to clear the history? When I click on “details” it shows the history and I'd like to delete it.

Comment: It’s a security feature that, to my knowledge, can’t be turned off, but I don’t have any supporting evidence, so I won’t put this as an answer. What you can do is turn off the alerts for it.

Comment: you can't : see this link: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938

Answer (score 1):

[Last account activity documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938), pointed out by [ajmalmhd04](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49820/last-account-activity-in-gmail#comment39903_49820), describes a way to turn off the alerts about unusual activity.

The point of this feature is to detect intrusion into your account; if an intruder was able to disable the feature that would largely defeat its purpose. Given this, and no evidence to the contrary, I conclude this activity report can't be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

It's not possible to clear the history in Gmail Last account activity as this is a feature to help the account owner to learn few details of the last access to his account.

## Explanation

From the reference

> ### What is 'Last account activity'?
>
> Last account activity shows you information about recent activity in your mail. Recent activity
> includes any time that your mail was accessed using a regular web
> browser,  a POP client, a mobile device, a third-party application
> etc. We'll list the IP address that accessed your mail, the associated
> location, as well as the time and date.

...

> If you're concerned about unauthorized access to your mail, you'll be
> able to use the data in the 'Access type' column to find out if and
> when someone accessed your mail. For instance, if the column shows any
> POP access, but you don't use POP to collect your mail, it may be a
> sign that your account has been compromised.

## References

- [Last account activity - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en)